# Creating a new database on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

There is very little correct information on the syntaxis, so I will try your place.

I am trying to set up a new MySQL DB through SSH and I get Error 1064 (42000) right in the first line:
mysql> create db media1

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

You'll want the full word database instead of just db

```
mysql> create database media1
```